# When I am using Github how can I create a version 1.1 of my application while I still maintain a version 1.0?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, github

I have an application that I am working on.  It's the Master Branch.  Now I would like to continue fixing bugs with that but at the same time work on the next version.

On my front-end I am using Visual Studio Community on the Mac OS.

Can someone explain to me how I can start on another version and work on that and then sometimes switch between versions to maintain the current app?

Comment: You may see how [OpenSSL is developed](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases), maybe the art of tags.

Comment: Regular Git branches are designed for just this sort of thing. You're probably best to find a good tutorial on the subject and go through it.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-Git-Basics